# How to open a new tab on the left end of the existing tabs in Firefox

Tags: firefox

How do I make Mozilla Firefox open new tabs (using the command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) at the near left end of the tab strip?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to do it without an add-on.

I installed Tab Mix Plus 0.4.1.0 and this solved the problem by adding the desired functionality.

**Edit**: After installing Tab Mix PLus 0.4.1.0, in order to open a new tab right after the tab you are currently in, you have to:

```
1. right-click on the current tab
2. choose the first option - "New Tab (After This Tab)"
```

Comment: Care to explain how you have done it? I can't find the option inside TabMixPlus

Comment: @Sekhemty done.

Comment: Oh well, I knew that; I wrongly understood that you wanted to open a new tab at the absolute left side of the tab-bar instead of directly to the right of the current one.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is possible in one step, but you can move the new tab left with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> and to the right with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd>.

Comment: Yes, I also came to the conclusion that it is not possible. Thanks for the advice though, it would be useful. I installed an add-on which permits opening a tab next to the current.

Comment: @Rayhunter: Cool. Please share this as a solution by by posting your own answer. It may help future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that it is not possible. The behavior of Ctrl + T is to open a new tab in the same way that the new tab button opens a new tab. It automatically defaults to the right side because of how the space is occupied. The left side is occupied so it starts to fill in the right. We also read left to right. Other than some crazy macro that creates the new tab and then shifts it to the left I don't think there is a simple way to do this. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: You and I read from left to right, but you never know about the next guy.

Comment: Fair enough. Arabic is read right to left.

Comment: When I have opened a lot of tabs and then open new blank tab for some reason, I must go to the end and bring it back which is very annoying. Anyway, I installed an addon which adds the desired functionality. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I don't think your made it clear that your intention was simply to have a tab open next to the current tab and not at the end. That's probably why no one suggested such a plugin. Anyway, you should answer your own question and post the solution to help anyone who finds this question later.

Answer (score 0):

No addons needed, simply visit `about:config` and toggle `browser.tabs.insertRelatedAfterCurrent` to `false` to load tabs on the far right. or `true` for relative (close to your tab on the left).

Comment: The option you mention only affects tabs that are opened, by clicking a link inside the webpage. When opening a new tab, you must use the option `browser.tabs.insertAfterCurrent`.